# Python Check if thread is alive

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

**Note: the suggested answer doesn't work as I call the function every x seconds.**

In python I have:

```
def inline_paid_generator(user_id, password):
    login_thread = threading.Thread(target=paid_generator, name="Register", args={user_id,password})
    login_thread.start()
```

How outside that function (from where I called it) how can I know if the thread is alive or not?

Comment: You need a reference to the thread to check if it is alive

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify *with what code* you call this function and *with what code* you want to know if the thread is running. If both are the same, this is trivial. If both are unrelated, this is much more difficult.

Comment: Are you aware of the [`is_alive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive) method?

Comment: @Tomerikoo are you aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65902236/python-runtimeerror-threads-can-only-be-started-once which lead me to this?

Comment: @john *Every* answer to this question as it currently stands will be a variation of "get the thread and call ``thread.is_alive()``". If you feel that repeatedly starting the same thread should somehow factor into the question or the answer, please add this information to the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65903208/python-thread-gets-called-wrongly

Comment: this will solve the issue here

Comment: That's a dead link... Anyway I don't see how it's related to your question. If your problem is starting the same thread twice then you should ask about that...

Comment: Why did you open a new question? You should [edit] this one. There is no reason to duplicate the same question

Answer (score 1):

You can set the thread as a global variable and only start it in the function, as following:

```
import time
import threading

def wait():
    time.sleep(5)

login_thread = threading.Thread(target=wait)

def start_inline_paid_generator():
    login_thread.start()

print(login_thread.is_alive()) # False

start_inline_paid_generator()

print(login_thread.is_alive()) # True
```

Then you can check anywhere in your program with login_thread.is_alive()

Comment: "you can set the thread as a global variable," how can I do this

Comment: you didn't answer my main question

Comment: RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

Comment: @john sorry, I misunderstood your question, you can go with the first one, you basically create the thread globally and then start it from a function. Then you can check anywhere in your program with login_thread.is_alive()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65902236/python-runtimeerror-threads-can-only-be-started-once

Comment: can u take a look?

Answer (score 1):

Return the created thread from the function and check [if it's alive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive):

```py
def inline_paid_generator(user_id, password):
    login_thread = threading.Thread(target=paid_generator, name="Register", args={user_id,password})
    login_thread.start()
    return login_thread

t = inline_paid_generator(...)
...
if not t.is_alive():
    t = inline_paid_generator(...)
```

Comment: the problem I want to check it before calling the function....

Comment: For more details see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65903208/python-thread-gets-called-wrongly

Comment: This ***is*** checking before the function call... What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I am calling this every 5 seconds, read that post

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65903208/python-thread-gets-called-wrongly